# Find limit of integral basic integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to solve this question:

> Find $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1(1-x)^n\cos{x}\ dx$$

I would really appreciate if you gave me some direction. The hint was that predecessor doesn't need to be found. thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $|\cos x|\leq 1$
$$-\frac{1}{n+1}=-\int_0^1(1-x)^ndx\leq\int_0^1(1-x)^n\cos{x}\;dx\leq\int_0^1(1-x)^ndx=\frac{1}{n+1}$$
By the squeeze theorem we get that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1(1-x)^n\cos{x}\;dx=0$$

Comment: +1, nice. Also took the liberty of LaTeX cleanup edits

Comment: Sure! Thank you. Im pretty new here and i'm still learning to write clean LaTeX